# Failed to clone <select> with ".select2 is not a function" error

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use `Select2` in dynamic form (add new row using jQuery clone), but apparently the cloned row doesn't pertain the functionality of `Select2`. Got the error

[image]

The 2nd select menu created but it generated error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
```

I'm using this HTML part:

```
<tbody id="treatmentlist">
    <tr class="itemData">
        <td>
           {{Form::select('treatments[]',$treatments, null, ['class' => 'form-control treatment', 'placeholder' => 'Select treatment' ])}}
        </td>
        <td><i class="fas fa-plus-circle" id='addRow'><i class="fas fa-minus-circle" id="delRow"></i></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And here is the script part:

```
@section('scripts')

    <script>
        $(".treatment").select2();
        $("#addRow").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $tr    = $(this).closest('.itemData');
            var $clone = $tr.clone();
            $tr.after($clone);
            $(".treatment").select2();
        });
    </script>

@endsection
```

Already try to add `select2('destroy')` without no luck.

Any suggestion how to make the newly cloned row keep the Select2 functionality?

Comment: Have a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175534/cloned-select2-is-not-responding

Comment: Thank you, I have look at that link earlier but just now understand the concept. Apparently the issue was related to the 2 things: 1). double Jquery loading & 2.) is the way select2 destroy method works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was related to the Laravel layout page (`app.blade.php`). It already loaded jQuery when calling bootstrap. So in the php I don't need to load jQuery again.

So revision on `app.blade.php`:

```
    <!-- Scripts, remove defer from app.js, move selec2.min.js & select2.min.css here -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>  
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

...
...

<!- and adding this part -->  
@yield('scripts')
```

On the php side, changes on the Select2 are :

1. Right after onClick function, call `select2('destroy')` first
2. then clone the row contain select element
3. finally reenable Select2 on the last newly added element using `select2()`.

```
@section('scripts')
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contents").children("td").children("select").select2();

    $(document).on('click', '#delRow', function(){
        if( $(this).closest('tr').is('tr:only-child') ) {
            alert('cannot delete last row');
        }
        else {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }

    });

    $("#addRow").click(function () {
        $("#contents").children("td").children("select").select2("destroy").end();

        // add <tr><td> directive first
        var newRow = '<tr id="contents"><td id="trx"><td> <i class="fas fa-minus-circle" id="delRow">';
        $(newRow).appendTo($("#treatmentlist"));

        // append select component on the last tr
        $('#treatmentlist tr:last').children("td:first-child").append(
            // clone the row and insert it in the DOM
            $("#contents").children("td").children("select").first().clone()
        );
        // enable Select2 on the last newly added element
        $('#treatmentlist tr:last').children("td").children("select").select2();
        // enable Select2 on the select elements
        $("#contents").children("td").children("select").select2();
    });
});
</script>
@endsection
```

While in the HTML, apply the changes as follow:

```
                <tbody id="treatmentlist">
                    <tr id="contents">
                        <td id="trx">
                            {{Form::select('treatments[]',$treatments, null, ['class' => 'form-control treatment', 'placeholder' => 'Select treatment' ])}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle" id='addRow'></td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment under 50 reputation, hope this example help you.
Explanition is here http://www.phpjavascript.com/2018_03_16_archive.html

```
$(function () {
    $("#addrow").click(function () {
        var tr = "<tr>" + "<td contenteditable='true'></td>".
                repeat($("#myTable tr:eq(0) td").length) + "</tr>"
        $("#myTable").append(tr);
    });
    $("#addcolumn").click(function () {
        $("#myTable tr").append($("<td contenteditable='true'></td>"));
        $(document).on('click', '.js-del-row', function () {
            $('#myTable').find('tr:last').remove();
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.js-del-column', function () {
            $('#myTable').find('td:last').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the issue wasn't about adding/deleting the row dynamically. But more about how to enable ```Select2``` in the newly cloned row.

Comment: Try  `$("#treatmentlist").children("select").select2();` or in your own code `$("#treatmentlist").select2();`